# Reversing an integer in java (question about the method)

Tags: java, math

The problem statement is kind of basic - if the input is a 32 bit signed integer output reversed integer, else output 0.

Here is the code I came up with

```java
public class Solution {
    public int reverse(int A) {
        if(A>=2143483647 || A<-2143483647)
        return 0;
        if(A>=0)
            return Integer.parseInt((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(A))).reverse().toString());
        else
            return -1*Integer.parseInt((new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(-1*A))).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

The solution is not accepted. The problem is in my code or the test cases?

Comment: Using Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE will make your code clean. BTW your ranges are wrong..... And that's another reason why you should use above constants.

Comment: `if the input is a 32 bit signed integer` Meaning, the input could be bigger than `int`. So, read it as long or big integer

Comment: Let us assume that your code is correct. If your input 'A' is 2143483646, reversing it will become 6463843412 and it is clearly out of integer range. Also as JavaFan said, your range value is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the input is int32, here is a possible approach, including checking for overflow.

```
public class Solution {
    public int reverse(int A) {
        //if(A < Integer.MIN_VALUE || A > Integer.MAX_VALUE) return 0;
        boolean neg = A < 0;
        A = Math.abs(A);
        long ret = 0;
        while(A != 0){
            ret = ret*10 + A%10;
            A = A/10;
        }
        if(ret > Integer.MAX_VALUE) return 0;
        return neg ? -(int)ret : (int)ret;
    }
}
```

Be mindful to change int to long if the input is bigger.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Could you tell me where you checked for overflow?

Comment: Here : `if(ret > Integer.MAX_VALUE) return 0;`

Comment: `System.out.println(reverse(Integer.MIN_VALUE));` gives `-126087180` which does not seem correct.

Answer (score 3):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56520699/238704) is close but misses some edge cases. Here is an answer based on the accepted answer, but hopefully correctly handles all cases.

```
public static int reverse(int A) {

    long aLong = Math.abs((long)A);
    long ret = 0;
    while (aLong != 0) {
        ret = ret * 10 + aLong % 10;
        aLong = aLong / 10;
    }
    if (A < 0) {
        ret = -ret;
    }

    if ((ret < Integer.MIN_VALUE) || (ret > Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (int) ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try reversing into a long parameter first (this guarantees that it'll not overflow), then do the checking afterwards.

```
public int reverse(int A) {
        long reversed; 
        if(A>=0)
            reversed=  reverseString(A);
        else
            reversed -1*  reverseString(-A) ;

        //we do the checking only after we have done the reverse.
        if(reversed > Integer.Max_VALUE || reversed < Integer.MIN_VALUE)
            return 0;
        else 
            return (int) reversed; //we do a down cast here.
}

public long reverseString(int A){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(""+A).reverse(); 
    String s = sb.reverse().toString(); 
    return Long.parseLong(s);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if it wasn't clear in the question but you aren't supposed to output the reversed number if it overflows (output 0 instead)

Comment: @DarkLord3 I see. what you can do is to do the reverse into a long, then do the checking afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This code will take care of positive and negative both numbers.After reversal if result is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE then it will return zero.

```
  public static int reverse(int x) {

     boolean positive = true;
     if(x < 0) {
         positive =  false;
         x = x * -1;
     }

     long result = 0;
     while(x > 0) {
         result = (result * 10) + (x % 10);
         x = x / 10;
     }

     if(result > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
         return 0;
     }

     return positive ? (int)result : (int)(result * -1);
  }
```